# Spring delete on OneToMany

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I have a child entity with mapping

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = {CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.DETACH})
List<Owner> ownerList;
```

And owner entity with

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "child_id", nullable = true)
Child child;
```

I want to delete OneToMany side without using cascade delete so Owner still exist, but with Child filed set as null, currently i get error that Child entity is still referenced from Owner, i would like it to be automatic without me having to write code that will unlink it and set Child field to null before deleting that Child entity. Is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use CascadeType.PERSIST on the ownerList and remove CascadeType.REFERESH,CascadeType.DETACH